# Writing to a json file in java using gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I am creating a java program which reads and writes data to json file using Gson libraries. In that when I write the new data to that json file it is written on the end of the file but not inside the object in json.

This is my json content:

```
{
  "employees":[
{
  "name":"xxxxxxx",
  "position":"yyyyyy"}
]
}
```

here is my code:

```
private static void writetojson(Hisab hi) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream os=new FileOutputStream(file,true);
        BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));

        Gson gson=new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        String temp=gson.toJson(hi);
        bw.append(temp);
        bw.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And the DTO class

```
public class Hisab {
String empname;
String position;

public String getempname() {
    return empname;
}

public void setempname(String empname) {
    this.empname = empname;
}



public String getposition() {
    return position;
}

public void setposition(String opsition) {
    this.position = position;
}
}
```

this is the output comes when I run the program:

```
     {
      "employees":[
       {
        "name":"xxxxxxx",
        "position":"yyyyyy"}
       ]
     }
     {
       "name":"zzzzzz",
       "position":"aaaaaaa"}
```

But this is my desired output:

```
    {
      "employees":[
      {
       "name":"xxxxxxx",
       "position":"yyyyyy"},
      {
       "name":"zzzzzz",
       "position":"aaaaaaa"}
     ]
    }
```

How to solve this problem. Please help me.

Comment: bw.append(temp) simply places the temp at the end of the json file. You need to drill down into the employees array and then put the desired object inside this array

Comment: How are you even getting this output? IMO, you should be getting only this `{
        "name":"xxxxxxx",
        "position":"yyyyyy"}`

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh i just add the content to object.and pass the object to `writetojson` method.I open the file in append mode

Comment: You should write the new contents to _another file_ and then rename to the original.

Comment: Where is `{ "employees":[ ] }` coming from

Comment: @fge could you pls give me explanation.because i am new to java

Comment: Ohh.... so that first part was already there in the file.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh yes the first part is already in the file which i open for read and write

Comment: First of all you need to read the json from file. Convert it to Java object using an appropriate DTO, then append the new Hisab's to the list in this Object. Now dump it to the file again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DTO needs to be,

```
class JsonCollection {

    ArrayList<Hisab> employees;

    public JsonCollectio() {
        this.employees = new ArrayList<Hisab>();
    }

    public void setEmployees( ArrayList<Hisab> emps ) {
        this.employees = emps;
    }

    public ArrayList<Hisab> getEmployees() {
         return this.employees;
    }

    public void addHisab( Hisab h ) {
         this.employees.add( h );
    } 

}
```

Now, your writeToJson method should be like,

```
public void writeToJson( Hisab h ) {
    // I am assuming this string has the current Json. Get this from file.
    String currentJsonString = "Some Json, you got from file";

    Gson gson=new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

    JsonCollection jsonColl = gson.fromJson( currentJsonString, JsonCollection.class );

    // Add your hisab to the collection.
    jsonColl.addHisab( h );

    // Now write this string to file
    String newJsonString =gson.toJson( jsonColl );

    System.out.print( newJsonString );

}
```

Comment: I tried it but `addHisab` method is not accessible using `jsonColl` object

Comment: Ohh... I understand the error.... you probably have some other class called JsonCollection. Rename this JsonCollection class to something else... like MyDtoCollection etc..

Comment: Sorry its my fault that i miss spelled the method name.After correct it works fine like i expected thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach suffers several problems, the first of it being that you risk losing both the original and the new content if appending fails for some reason.

What is more, your storage format is rather strange; why the single object key? It's not needed; just scrap it, and store the array directly.

Now, I don't do Gson but Jackson, so I can't help you with the actual code but basically your code should look like this:

```
final Charset cs = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
final Path toReplace = Paths.get("whereverisyourfile");
final Path newContents = toReplace.resolveSibling("newcontents.json");

try (
    final BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(toReplace, cs);
    final BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(newContents, cs,
        StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
) {
    // read old content, manipulate, write new contents
}

// IOException is THROWN, not logged

Files.move(newContents, toReplace, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING,
    StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);
```

Now, as to how to read old content and write, you have two options:

- read the whole thing as a POJO which you modify before writing;
- use the streaming API of your library.

The above is your choice and depends on the size of the data stored etc.

And this method should THROW the IOException if any, so that you can deal with anomalous situations. Just `printStackTrace()`ing an exception is never the good option.

Answer (score 1):

Create your Base Classes

```
public class Employee
{
    private String name;
    private String position;
    // getter setter
}


public class RootObject
{
    private ArrayList<Employee> employees;
    // getter setter
}

Gson gson = new Gson();
RootObject rootObj = new RootObject();
rootObj.setEmployees(yourList);
// convert java object to JSON format,
// and returned as JSON formatted string
String json = gson.toJson(rootObj);
```